# Snaps failing when trying to run alacritty

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, terminal-emulator, snap

I'm trying to run alacritty on a near-fresh install of Ubuntu. As far as I can tell I followed [the guide](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/INSTALL.md#shell-completions), and running `infocmp alacritty` doesn't return an error, though the response is unintelligible to me.

However, when I try to run alacritty I get the response...

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to initialize any backend!
    Wayland status: NoCompositorListening
    X11 status: LibraryOpenError(
    OpenError {
        kind: Library,
        detail: "opening library failed (/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26\' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6)); opening library failed (/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26\' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so))"
    }
)
', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/winit-0.15.1/src/platform/linux/mod.rs:428:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

This is my first attempt at using Linux and I cant work out whats wrong. Running `sudo apt-get install -y libc6-dev` reveals that libc is up-to-dat so I don't know why it won't open.

Comment: Have you tried the .deb from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alacritty.mirror/)?

Comment: Yes, this worked. If you want to provide this an answer I can mark it as correct. I assume I just needed a better source.

Comment: I wrote up a quick answer for you. And, yeah, it's probably best that it have an accepted answer for the next folks that come along searching for a fix.

Comment: Honestly these websites are like gold dust for newbies such as myself who can get stuck dong the most mundane and trivial of tasks. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When confronted with errors in snap applications, it's a good idea to look around to see if the applications are available elsewhere. In my case, I use snaps only when there's no reasonable alternative method of getting the application.

In this case, you want Alacritty. You can download the latest version of the application, in .deb format, from the author's SourceForge mirror located [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alacritty.mirror/). Just click the download. It's a complete and up-to-date mirror of their github and the newest .deb will download automatically.

To install this, I actually recommend using gdebi. If you're after .deb files, gdebi is probably in your default repositories - or maybe even already installed. If it's not installed, install it with:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

After that, I use gdebi to install the .deb files. This not only provides a nice easy GUI install, it also means you can later click on the original .deb file and, in the upper right (after it's finished doing what it does while opening) select the "Remove Package" to uninstall it.